# Is super in python redundant?

Tags: python, inheritance

In the following example I get the same output if I replace super in CL2 with self.test() which is " in cl2 test cl5". How exactly does super make any difference.

```
class CL1(object):
    def test(self):
        print "test cl1"

class CL2(CL1):
    def abc(self):

        print "in cl2"
        super(CL2,self).test()
        #self.test()

class CL3(CL1):
    def test(self):
        print "test cl3"

class CL5(CL1):
    def test(self):
        print "test cl5"

class CL4(CL2,CL5,CL3):
    def add(self):
        print 'cl4'

def main()
   o=CL4()
   o.abc()
if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Comment: Interesting question. When subclassing any other object than "object" it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: `super` is misnamed; it doesn't necessarily refer to the (single) statically defined parent class of the class in which it is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using `super`, then inside the class `CL2`, it will call its parent(CL1)'s `test()` method implicitly.

But the ambiguous problem occurs when class `CL2` also define a method named `test()` (this is called method overriding in OOP). The default is using the current class's `test()` method, but if you want to call the parent's one instead, then it's when you need to use `super` to call its super class's `test()` method explicitly.

Consider this illustration:

```
class CL1(object):
    def test(self):
        print "test CL1"

class CL2(CL1):
    def test(self):
      print "test CL2"

    def abc(self):

        print "in CL2"
        super(CL2,self).test()
        self.test()

o=CL2()
o.abc()
```

Will output:

```
in CL2
test CL1
test CL2
```

Comment: You don't need `super` here; you could just as easily call `CL1.test(self)` explicitly.

Comment: Yes. Thank you chepner. I know. But what if the name of class `CL1` got changed?

Comment: If you change the name, you can change the code associated with it, too. It's more *convenient* if you are using `super`, but it's not *necessary*, and  that's not why `super` was added to the language.

Comment: I didn't mention that it is the reason why `super` was created.

Comment: The question asks if `super` is redundant; the reason why `super` was added to the language is pretty critical to answering that. All you've done is demonstrate something `super` is specifically *not* required for.

Answer (score -2):

`super` is not just a convenience for leaving the name of the base class out of your child-class methods; it is designed for *cooperative* inheritance, in which properly-designed classes will call overriden methods in the correct order according to the C3 linearization algorithm.

`super` does not necessarily refer to the statically declared parent of the class you are defining. Consider the following code:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("A.foo")

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("B before super")
        super().foo()
        print("B.foo")

class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("C before super")
        super().foo()
        print("C.foo")

class D(B, C):
    def foo(self):
        print("D before super")
        super().foo()
        print("D.foo")

print(D.__mro__)
d = D()
d.foo()
```

The call `super().foo()` inside `B.foo` does not call `A.foo` when you run `d.foo()`; it runs `C.foo` instead, because `C` comes immediately after `B` in the method resolution order (MRO) of class `D`.

If you are not OK with `B.foo` not *always* calling `A.foo` immediately, regardless of the type of `self`, don't use `super`. By using `super`, you are agreeing to the semantics it was designed to support, and should document the method as using `super`. Otherwise, just use `A.foo(self)` instead, and document the fact that you are *not* using `super`.